# How should "weak" resources be handled in a RESTful website?

Tags: rest

In RESTful websites, each resource should be identified by an URI. But how should I handle what are called "weak entities" in relational databases, aka, ressources that only make sense when related to another resource? Should these have specific URIs pointing to them too?

To give an example: Say I have a website for showing events going on in a city. Each event can have comments posted by users.

An `event` is a resource, with corresponding URI (`/events/:id`). 
But should each `comment` have an URI, too? Like `/events/:eventid/comments/:commentid` ? Comments only make sense when they're associated with the corresponding event, so having a page just to represent one message seems weird/unnecessary. I only want the comments to appear on the page of the event.

I guess the `/events/:eventid/comments/:commentid` URI could be used for a `DELETE` request, but what should it return to a `GET` request?

Answer (score 3):

> An `event` is a resource, with corresponding URI (`/events/:id`).
> But should each `comment` have an URI, too? Like `/events/:eventid/comments/:commentid` ?

If `comment` is a *resource*, it must have an identifier, but it doesn't mean that you have to support all operations for such resource. The server can return a response with the [`405`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) status code if a method is not supported by the target resource:

> [**6.5.5.  405 Method Not Allowed**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5)
>
> The `405` (Method Not Allowed) status code indicates that the method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource. [...]

---

> I guess the `/events/:eventid/comments/:commentid` URI could be used for a `DELETE` request, but what should it return to a `GET` request?

Return a representation of the comment with the given identifier.

Answer (score 2):

> In RESTful websites, each resource should be identified by an URI. But how should I handle what are called "weak entities" in relational databases, aka, ressources that only make sense when related to another resource? Should these have specific URIs pointing to them too?

It depends.  An important thing to recognize is that resources and entities are *not* one to one.  You are allowed to have many resources (web pages) that include information from the same entity.

Jim Webber described the distinction this way

> The web is not your domain, it's a document management system.  All the HTTP verbs apply to the document management domain. URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation.

[Domain Driven Design for Restful Systems](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc)

> I guess the /events/:eventid/comments/:commentid URI could be used for a DELETE request, but what should it return to a GET request?

As noted by [Cassio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49362776/54734), [405 Method Not Allowed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.5) is the correct status code to use if the client erroneously sends a request with an unsupported method.  [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) is the appropriate mechanism for informing a client of which methods are currently supported by a resource.

You could also have it respond by redirecting the client to the `/events/:eventId` resource; it might even make sense to take advantage of [URI Fragment support](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), and redirect the client to `/events/:eventid#:commentid` - allowing the client to use its own fragment discovery to identify the specific comment within the representation of the event.

Or, if there are useful integrations that you want to support, you could simply have this resource return a representation that exposes the integrations.

Comment: https://yow.eventer.com/events/1004/talks/1047 got a connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the client wants to work with the domain. Would an app want to get a list of all the comments for an event? Are users allowed to update their commments? Or are they anonymous comments?

If you plan to only ever use the same page to display the backend information of events and comments, then you prolly don't need a separate comments api. If you want to open the dataset to app vendors (perhaps you might want to develop an app in future) a comments api would be handy. i.e. get all comments for an event.